# How to implement images in Shopify source code?

Tags: html, css, shopify

I hope to get help.
I worked on my theme in vscode and implemented one new section witch is super simple (just some text and an icon), it works totally fine (shopify cli).

Now I wonted to implement it on my Live theme and the icons are broken.

here my code:

[image]

Hope I someone can point my in the right direction.
I am not a programmer but have some understanding of programming :)

Comment: Post the code directly instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the src for the image is correct for the Live theme?

Answer (score 0):

To include pictures you cannot use a local path. You need to use the `asset_img_url` media filter.
So your code should look like

```
<img class="hacken" src="{{'tick.png' | asset_img_url: 'original'}}" width="20" height="20" loading="lazy"/>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Can you please tell me what the 'original' means? I've tried  it and it did not work

Comment: @StefanTuaev 'original' means to use the original size. Other possible values are like '100x' for a 100px size. What it was wrong is that i used only one `{`. I fixed the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. With your help I've managed to complete my task.